# Video.js player in Fancybox issue in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, fancybox, video.js

I have a HTML5 video (using Video.js) playing in a Fancybox popup. The videos play well in all browsers except IE. (partially yes).

It plays for the first time in IE 8 and when I retry to play, nothing happens. And sometimes it plays in a transparent form.

I could not find anything on this. Here is the link of my site.

http://site.com/oxwall/my-videos

I am providing video in three different formats: mp4, webm and ogv

I tried to find the solution here in other question.. but this case looks different from other issues.

1) Tried the below code to the mp4 type file.

```
type="video/mp4"; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"
```

2) Added the preload option in the  tag as suggested in other SO questins.

```
preload="none"
```

3) DOCTYPE is already added. I have no control on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how come you say `The videos play well in all browsers` ... don't see them playing at all in Chrome or Firefox for instance

Comment: Sorry Sir. It was due to some server cache. Cleared up the smarty template cache. Please try now.

Comment: Hope the videos are playing from the link.

Comment: Please let me know if you still face any issue on this page.

Comment: Sir, can you help me on this? I am totally stuck on this.. Please let me know if you need any other information this.

Comment: @JFK : Can you please assist me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the IE was in some compatibility quirk mode(the samell icon on the address bar). When I change that everything went fine.